# Adding jar files in each jvm run dont seem to work

Tags: java, postgresql, jar

I hava a java program which requires me to add an additional jar file when I run it.

What I first do is:

```
$ javac -classpath postgresql-42.1.4.jar myFile.java
```

It executes with no errors. But when I then try to do:

```
$ java -classpath postgresql-42.1.4.jar myFile
```

It says:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class myFile
```

The current folder im in looks like this:

`postgresql-42.1.4.jar`  `myFile.class`  `myFile.java`

There are no errors in myFile.java file (it is setup correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overridden the classpath, so it only contains the driver. You need to include your current directory there as well.

`java -cp postgresql-42.1.4.jar:. myFile`

Also please adhere to Java naming conventions. It should be `MyFile`, not `myFile`.

Comment: Thanks! But when I run this, I only get info on how to use `java` command. Like: `Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]`

Comment: Oops, my mistake. The separator is `:` on *nix and `;` on windows.

Comment: Ah, yes. that did the trick. Thanks! Is the dot (`.`) after `:` a concatenation operator?

Comment: No, it's the current directory. It will be included in the classpath.